# Room Booking Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem in writing the sql to get the availables rooms from the tables.

My tables structures are given below.

```
Table Booking
ID | START_DATE | END_DATE


Table BookingRoom (Intermediate Table)
ID   | BOOKING_ID   |ROOM_ID
```

A Room can be linked to many bookings and a booking can contain many rooms

```
Table Room
Contains the ID room
```

I have Tried This but there is a probleme if a room is linked to 2 differents bookings in separate dates the comparaison will be maked with only the first booking id

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.ID FROM room AS r ,booking AS b,bookingroom AS br
 WHERE r.ID = br.ID_ROOM
 AND b.ID = br.ID_BOOKING
 AND (
           b.END_DATE < '05/14/2013'
        OR b.START_DATE > '05/15/2013'
     )
```

**Can someone help me to write the SQL to get the available rooms between a checkin and checkout date.**

Comment: Are you looking for rooms at a specific date/time or during a period?

Comment: In fact i'm searching for availables rooms between a check in date and a checkout date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is the list of rooms available for the entire range of desired dates, then something like the following might work:

```
Select Room.Id
From Room
Where Room.Id Not In    (
                        Select RoomId
                        From BookingRoom
                            Join Booking
                                On Booking.Id = BookingRoom.BookingId
                        Where Booking.StartDate <= 'DesiredEndDate'
                            And Booking.EndDate >= 'DesiredStartDate'
                        )
Order By Room.Id
```

So, using the original example, we might get:

```
Select Room.Id
From Room
Where Room.Id Not In    (
                        Select RoomId
                        From BookingRoom
                            Join Booking
                                On Booking.Id = BookingRoom.BookingId
                        Where Booking.StartDate <= '2013-05-15'
                            And Booking.EndDate >= '2013-05-14'
                        )
Order By Room.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define a clear recordsets for "all bookings made on day X", and then use an outer join to retrieve those rooms that don't have a booking for said day.

```
SET @myDate = #someDay#
SELECT R.ID
FROM Room R
WHERE R.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT BR.ROOM_ID
    FROM BookingRoom BR
    INNER JOIN Booking B ON BR.Booking_ID = B.ID
    WHERE @myDate BETWEEN B.start_date and B.end_date
)
```

**Edit:**

Since you want ALL open rooms during a reservation, you'll need to do a more complicated query.  I'll assume that you already have the dates in question loaded outside, since doing a date-based many-to-many query is a PITA.

```
SET @dateStart = #Start#
SET @dateEnd = #End#

SELECT R.ID
FROM Room R
WHERE R.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT BR.ROOM_ID
    FROM BookingRoom BR
    INNER JOIN Booking B ON BR.Booking_ID = B.ID
    WHERE B.start_date BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
    AND B.end_date BETWEEN @dateStart AND @dateEnd
)
```