# How to use WhereNotIn and with in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

This is my Query eloquent created, i need to get materials that are available in dates.

I have guided from here:
[Room Booking Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16554649/room-booking-query)

How to fix these errors?

```
Material::with(['orders_material' => function($query)  use ($begin_date,
    $end_date, $begin_hour, $hour_final) 

 {
    $query->whereNotIn(
    $query->where('date_begin', '>=', $begin_date)
    ->where('date_begin', '<=', $end_date)
    ->where('date_final', '>=', $begin_date)
    ->where('date_final', '<=', $end_date)
    ->where('hour_begin', '>=', $begin_hour)
    ->where('hour_begin', '<=', $hour_final)
    ->where('hour_final', '>=', $begin_hour)
    ->where('hour_final', '<=', $hour_final);
    //->wherePivot('Material_id', null)
    //->wherePivot('Orders_id', null)
    );
  }
```

The syntax is not correct, what syntax I can use?

Comment: What error you are receiving ? You have to use `get()` to get result

Comment: You are using WhereNotIn incorrectly, it should be `$query->whereNotIn('column_name', $someArrayHere)`

Comment: @HelloSpeakman it's ```Material::with(['orders_material' => ->whereNotIn('Material_id', function($q)  use ($begin_date, $end_date, $begin_hour, $hour_final) 
     
     {
        $q->where('date_begin', '>=', $begin_date)```, but column_name it's a pivot name, what i should select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`whereHas` is the appropriate clause in this case.

Also, use `whereBetween` when querying for values falling between a min and max. It will simplify your query quite a bit:

```
Material::whereHas(['orders_material' => function($query) use ($begin_date, $end_date, $begin_hour, $hour_final) {
    $query->whereBetween('date_begin', [$begin_date, $end_date])
          ->whereBetween('date_final', [$begin_date, $end_date])
          ->whereBetween('hour_begin', [$begin_hour, $hour_final])
          ->whereBetween('hour_final', [$begin_hour, $hour_final]);
})->get();
```

Comment: Works! Thank you! :)